# How can I call all products who were created by User?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb+moongose, I can already do the basic CRUD, but I'm having trouble getting all the products that are created by the user, I don't know If I'm doing it correctly, I tried to use it.

```
user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
```

For example.

```
Show all products that is created by User1
```

ProductSchema.js

import mongoose from 'mongoose'

```
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
    categories: {type: Array},
    price: {type: Number},
    productImage: {type: String}
   },
{ timestamps: { createdAt: true } }
   )

export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

UserSchema.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String,  required: true},
    email: {type: String,  unique: true, required: true},
    studentid: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    isAdmin:{type: Boolean, default: false},
},
{ timestamps: { createdAt: true } }
)

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Controller.js

```
export const getProductOfUsers = async (req,res) =>{
  try {
    const posts = await Product.find({user_id: req.user.id})
    res.status(200).json(posts)

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({message: error.message})  
  }
}
```

Router.js

```
router.get('/customerproduct', getProductOfUsers)
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Possible checks you can do is, in products collection if user id is updated correctly or not, and the req.user is populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo in your controller.js. req.user maybe not defined. Just turn it req.body.user.